# What are these ladders on the sides of houses on Åland for?

Tags: identify-this

While travelling on the Åland islands, I noticed that a lot of houses have ladders reaching from under the windows to a meter or 2 from the ground. I had seen similar ladders on the sides of houses in the rest of Sweden, but they stretched until the roof to make it easier to de-snow during the winter ; the ones on Åland are shorter.
The only explanation that I can think of is that the ladders would make it easier to evacuate in case of a fire, but then why are they only on the houses of Åland?

[image][image]

Comment: They do indeed look like fire escapes, given their placement relative to balconies and windows.  I have no idea why they would be only in Åland, however, so I cannot answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

The premise of your question is mistaken. [Åland islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85land_Islands) are a part of Finland, not Sweden so therefore the Finnish fire regulations are in effect. According to the [Finnish fire regulations](http://www.spek.fi/Suomeksi/Turvatietoa/Paloturvallisuus/Pientaloasujalle/Poistumistikkaat) (link in Finnish) if the window is more than 3.5 meters from the ground the ladders are needed. You can see these ladders all over Finland.

Comment: Recalling my many visits to Helsinki and my extended stay there, I don’t recall any ladders at residential buildings in Itä-Pasila or indeed elsewhere so I wonder if that only applies to single-family homes?

Comment: @Jan This regulation is only for "small houses". It seems that apartment buildings in Finland don't require a separate fire escape, as the stairs in the building are considered the safest way to exit the building.